# Symfony2 collection with iterator

Tags: symfony

I have a form with collections. Everything works fine, i read this chapter in symfony cookbook.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Now i want to inject an counter/iterator to the collection through twig.

I render my collection like this

```
<ul class="sections accordion list-unstyled" data-prototype="{% filter escape %}{% include 'AppQuestionnaireBundle:Additional:section-collection.html.twig' with {'form': form.section.vars.prototype, 'index' : ITERATOR} %}{% endfilter %}">
```

Is there a possibility to inject an counter into "section-collection.html.twig" or should i realize this with javascript?

Comment: if your are inside a loop block you can use `loop.index0` otherwise, its not clear what you want to achieve.